# Cannot make a generic fake for a class using object

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, microsoft-fakes

Cannot make a generic fake for a class using object like

```
Fakes.ShimDataServiceRepository<object>.AllInstances.GetEntitiesExpressionOfFuncOfT0Boolean = (instance, filter) =>
{

return null;

}
```

The call goes to actual code implementation.

But when we specify the object type, it is working

```
Fakes.ShimDataServiceRepository<Customer>.AllInstances.GetEntitiesExpressionOfFuncOfT0Boolean = (instance, filter) =>
{

return null;

}
```

But i need a general single fake for all objects so no need to repeat the code for each objects.

My question is why the fake with `<object>` is not working?. As it is the parent of all the classes.

Please any one help me :(

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why the fake with  is not working?. As it is the parent of all the classes.

Object is the parent of all classes, but `DataServiceRepository<object>` is not the parent of `DataServiceRepository<Customer>`.

A generic class with different concrete types is no longer "the same class". The two types don't share statics or fakes.